# Embedding Julia into C#: Garbage Collector Rewrite into C# Issues and Questions

Tags: c#, c, garbage-collection, interop, julia

Currently I am working on writing a C# script that can call functions written in Julia modules. Julia provides a C API that allows functions to be called in Julia. I have managed to get functions written in Julia modules to be called from C#, and get array data to be passed back and forth.

However, I am not entirely sure how to control the garbage collector correctly. 
This code is the inline code provided by **julia.h**, that tells the Julia garbage collector that the variables pointed to by args are being used in another script and shouldn't be moved/deallocated. Each call (`jl_gc_push()` or `jl_gc_push_args()` pushes a thing to the stack that the garbage collector uses.

**Code in julia.h:**

```
#define jl_pgcstack (jl_get_ptls_states()->pgcstack)
#define JL_GC_PUSH1(arg1)               \
    void *__gc_stkf[] = {(void*)3, jl_pgcstack, arg1};     \
    jl_pgcstack = (jl_gcframe_t*)__gc_stkf;

...(similar functions for 2, 3, 4)............

#define JL_GC_PUSH5(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)        \
    void *__gc_stkf[] = {(void*)11, jl_pgcstack, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5};              \
    jl_pgcstack = (jl_gcframe_t*)__gc_stkf;
#define JL_GC_PUSHARGS(rts_var,n)                     \
    rts_var = ((jl_value_t**)alloca(((n)+2)*sizeof(jl_value_t*)))+2;   \
    ((void**)rts_var)[-2] = (void*)(((size_t)(n))<<1);              \
    ((void**)rts_var)[-1] = jl_pgcstack;                 \
    memset((void*)rts_var, 0, (n)*sizeof(jl_value_t*));        \
    jl_pgcstack = (jl_gcframe_t*)&(((void**)rts_var)[-2])
#define JL_GC_POP() (jl_pgcstack = jl_pgcstack = jl_pgcstack->prev)
```

`jl_get_ptls_states` returns a struct that has a pointer called `pgcstack`. I believe that is the thing that the garbage collector uses. `arg1` is supposed to be of type `jl_value_t*`, and `rts_var` is supposed to be of type `jl_value_t**`.

**Question 1:**

I can't reconcile this particular difference between this line in JL_GC_PUSH1 (and the other JL_GC_PUSH# ones):

```
void *__gc_stkf[] = {(void*)3, ...
```

and this line in JL_GC_PUSHARGS:

```
((void**)rts_var)[-2] = (void*)(((size_t)(n))<<1);
```

If I used JL_GC_PUSH1 to tell the garbage collector I want a variable to be ignored, it would set the first variable in the array to be 3. However, if I were to use JL_GC_PUSHARGS, it would set it to 2. I thought bit shifting to the left filled in with zeroes? I understand how everything else works in these functions though.

**Question 2:**
I'm writing a C# function that does what JL_GC_PUSHARGS does, except it takes in `params IntPtr` instead of `jl_value_t**`. Is it safe if I allocate memory like this? Does anyone know if Julia will deallocate as necessary, or will I have to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal on the memory? If Julia does it anyways and I call Marshal.FreeHGlobal, will there be issues?

**C# version:**

```
public unsafe static void JL_GC_PUSHARGS(params IntPtr[] args) {
        int l = args.Length;
        IntPtr* pgcstacknew = (IntPtr*) Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>() * (l + 2)).ToPointer();
        pgcstacknew[0] = (IntPtr)(2 * l + 1); //related to Question 1
        pgcstacknew[1] = jl_pgcstack();
        for(uint i = 2; i < l + 2; i++){
            pgcstacknew[i] = args[i - 2];
        }
        jl_pgcstack() = pgcstacknew;
        //I'm still having issues with this line ^^  
    }
```

For now just assume that `jl_pgcstack()` is equivalent to the inline function written in C. I'm having issues with that, but that's a different problem.

Comment: While likely possible in principle, hooking directly into the GC stack is probably not ideal. Another way to interact with the Julia GC is to push references into a global array. This is what pyjulia does ([via PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/blob/1d755f27fd440a43b9a792919fee0531495754e0/src/pytype.jl#L433-L440)), and see also the [closely related discussion](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Garbage-Collection-Safety-1) in the ccall part of manual. Hopefully this is enough to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1

The `JL_GC_PUSH1` and `JL_GC_PUSHARGS` macros have different stack layout. The low bit indicates which one it is.

> Question 2

Julia won't deallocate anything, since there isn't supposed to be anything allocated when creating a gc-frame. If you're going to allocate, it's usually better to go through the Julia API and build a simulated ref-counting scheme on top of an `ObjectIdDict` (jl_eqtable_get/put).

A direct translation of JL_GC_PUSHARGS should look something like:

```
unsafe {
    // JL_GC_PUSHARGS
    uint l = args.Length;
    IntPtr* pgcstacknew = stackalloc IntPtr[l + 2];
    pgcstacknew[0] = (IntPtr)(l << 2); // how many roots?
    pgcstacknew[1] = jl_pgcstack(); // link to previous gc-frame
    for (uint i = 0; i < l; i++) { // copy the args to the stack roots
        pgcstacknew[i + 2] = args[i];
    }
    jl_pgcstack() = pgcstacknew; // install frame at top of gc-stack
}
// <do stuff with args here>
unsafe {
    // JL_GC_POP
    jl_pgcstack() = pgcstacknew[1]; // remove frame from gc-stack
}
```

Another alternative is to use the `jl_call` set of functions, which includes the setup and teardown of a gc frame (as well as an exception frame).

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a detailed answer. Thanks! I was actually trying to do what Isaiah commented, but if that doesn't work I will return to this.